# json_decode not working with php

Tags: php, json

My json is getting to the server:

[{"color":"Red","size":"YXS","quantity":"10"}],[{"color":"Blue","size":"YXS","quantity":"10"}]

However, json_decode isn't working to convert it back to an object after the server. using var_dump, the object is null. I can print_r the variable and it prints out fine.

Any ideas? (I see there are other questions submitted on this, but I have tried all of them and nothing works).

building the JSON string in javascript, it gets saved to a hidden form field.

```
     var str = ""; 
     for(i=0;i<orderDetails.length;i++){
           str += JSON.stringify(orderDetails[i]) + ",";
     }
```

on the display page I have:

```
  <hr />

<?php



var_dump(json_decode(($orderData)));

?>
```

print_r($orderData); displays the string I pasted in.

json_decode($orderData) is null

EDIT:

I change my JSON builder to remove the brackets in my middle like @PaulPro suggested.

```
     var str = ""; 
     for(i=0;i<orderDetails.length;i++){
           str += JSON.stringify(orderDetails[i]) + ",";
     }
     str = str.substr(0,str.length-1); // remove last comma
     str = str.replace("],[",","); // remove brackets in the middle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not JSON, it looks like two JSON arrays joined by a comma. It would be valid JSON if the whole thing was surrounded by `[` and `]` making it an array of arrays:

```
[[{"color":"Red","size":"YXS","quantity":"10"}],[{"color":"Blue","size":"YXS","quantity":"10"}]]
```

It would also be valid if you replaced the `],[` between objects with just a `,`:

```
[{"color":"Red","size":"YXS","quantity":"10"},{"color":"Blue","size":"YXS","quantity":"10"}]
```

For future reference, you can use [json_last_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) and in PHP 5.5+ [json_last_error_msg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to assist in debugging issues with json_decode and json_encode.

Comment: It appers I took a wrong path somewhere, as I haven't done PHP is a while. I have a form with "order details" that is on the same page. I the main form on the page. Then I have a second form on the page and when I submit that form, I am grabbing the submit with jquery and trying to build string based data that I can add to a hidden form field to get a single post back to the server to process the data.

Comment: @Scotty After seeing the edits in your question. I believe you can replace all that code with `JSON.stringify( orderDetails );`. In other words, serialize the whole array to JSON at once instead of doing each element individually and then concatenating them together.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the square brackets near the comma and it will work! In fact that you are having two arrays in between an outer array there have to be a square bracket in the front an a closing square bracket in the end of the json string to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error, because your json string isn't valid. It seems, this should be an array, but the brackets around are missing.

```
$json = '[{"color":"Red","size":"YXS","quantity":"10"}],[{"color":"Blue","size":"YXS","quantity":"10"}]';
$validJson = "[$json]";
$data = json_decode($validJson, true);
```